# UIImageView does not rotate when I change the ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, rotation

I have a rotating UIImageView in ViewController. But the UIImageView does not rotate when I change the ViewController to SecondViewController and SecondViewController to ViewController.

Extension ;

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIView {

    //Start Rotating view
    func startRotating(duration: Double = 1) {
        let kAnimationKey = "rotation"

        if self.layer.animation(forKey: kAnimationKey) == nil {
            let animate = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
            animate.duration = duration
            animate.repeatCount = Float.infinity

            animate.fromValue = 0.0
            animate.toValue = Float(Double.pi * 2.0)
            self.layer.add(animate, forKey: kAnimationKey)
        }
    }

    //Stop rotating view
    func stopRotating() {
        let kAnimationKey = "rotation"

        if self.layer.animation(forKey: kAnimationKey) != nil {
            self.layer.removeAnimation(forKey: kAnimationKey)
        }
    }

}


viewdidload ;

logo.startRotating(duration: 6)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kerim Sener there is nothing wrong in your rotation code just call the function in view did appear method like below.. in your view controller.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        logo.startRotating(duration: 6)
    }
```

Comment: I clicked but said that I should wait 1 minute for stackoverflow. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

When you are transactioning from the second navigation controller to your first view controller on the navigation stack; The second one will not be instantiated again because it is still alive on memory; then the `viewDidLoad` delegate will not be called again;

Then you can pop the second one, if you are using the navigation controller, e.g

```
self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Or

You can override the `viewWillAppear` method to call your function

```
logo.startRotating(duration: 6)
```

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem with the override method

Comment: You are welcome :) I recommend you to learn more about the viewcontroller lifecycle

Comment: Is there a resource you suggest?